# How do I get my api data to display as a single item instead of printing vertically letter by letter?

Tags: react-native

I am starting to grasp fetch and using an API but I am trying to refer to a code source that used currencies and applying it to my own version but using an API that returns a random activity. The project I am using to better grasp my understanding is react-native expo cli

What I want it to do:
Press the search button -> returns random activity to do.

Currently, it is doing this but because my old API returns an array of objects for different currencies and my current random activity API returns just one activity I believe this is why my formatting is off but after reading and trying out different .then actions I can't seem to understand fully how to display my random activity properly instead of the multiple lines of the same activity I am currently getting I want it to display only once. (My prior question had the letters vertical which I have since fixed).

here is the link for the API i want to use https://www.boredapi.com/
here is the link for the old API https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD

Thanks!

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, SafeAreaView, Button, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Item = ({ item }) => {
  return(
    <View>

      <Text>{item.value}</Text>
      
    </View>
  )
}
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  var searchForActivity = () => {
    fetch('http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        var array = Object.keys(json.activity).map((key) => ({
          value: json.activity,
        }));

        setData(array);
      });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    searchForActivity();
  }, []);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome to Activity Finder</Text>
      <FlatList data = {data} renderItem={Item} />
      <Button title='Search' onPress={searchForActivity} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

[image: Picture of current webpage with same activity displaying multiple times]

Answer (score 0):

Your api call returns a single object like this

```js
{
  "activity": "Write a list of things you are grateful for",
  "type": "relaxation",
  "participants": 1,
  "price": 0,
  "link": "",
  "key": "2062010",
  "accessibility": 0
}
```

Since your data is not going to be an array you should change the `data` initial state to something like null.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

You're currently looping over the `keys` of the `activity` property, which are just indices. Then map over all the keys and return an object with the property `value` which just has the `json.activity`. This does not make any sense. You can set the `json` directly to the state like this since you don't need an array if you only want to display one activity.

```js
var searchForActivity = () => {
  fetch("http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      setData(json);
    });
};
```

By this point you can't use `FlatList` anymore since you `data` in not an array anymore, in your `App` you should change the `FlatList` with the `Item` component you made.

```js
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Welcome to Activity Finder</Text>
          <Item item={data} />
          <Button title="Search" onPress={searchForActivity} />
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Note that in your `Item` component you use a `value` property. This property does not exists on the data you get back from the api and should be changed to `activity` for it to show the name of the activity.

```js
<Text>{item.value}</Text>
// change value with activity
<Text>{item.activity}</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but now when I use your code it just returns "your value". Should I be putting something else there instead?

Comment: Nope I just saw it in your code snippet, if you don't use it you can just replace the code inside `then` when receiving the json with `setData((prevData) => [...prevData, fetchedActivity]);`

Comment: Okay, when I do that it doesnt work and when I apply to full code above it still only returns "your value" and then it just repeats it instead of returning a different activity from the API everytime the button is pressed

Comment: I updated my answer, everytime the function runs it will add the new activity to the list

Comment: Thank you  but i think maybe you don't understand what I am wanting to do as your updated answer also does not work. And I am not wanting to add it to a list. I just want to have the random activity displayed everytime the button is hit

Comment: @DevSteph I updated my answer the new needs of your question